# Local RDLC report using spatial data

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, rdlc

I am currently attempting to create a local RDLC report that contains a map within visual studio 2012.

This report will fetch its data from a SQL dataset that contains a spatial data column. This dataset is generated from stored procedure and contains a field with the geography data type.

The problem I am having is that as soon as I attempt to create the dataset I receive the error within the screen shot below.

Could someone please explain how I can create a dataset with the geography data type if I cannot use the wizard?. I apologies in advance if I have missed something incredibly obvious...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive managed to get around the issue.

I used the guide below to assist me with creating a manual dataset.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272532(v=vs.110).aspx